# How do you declare a ranges-v3 view return value?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Currently, I can compose ranges-v3 views like this:

```
auto v = ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::filter([](int l){return l>5;});
```

But if I wanted to return v from a function I'd need to know its type. What is the type of a ranges-v3 view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++14 you can use `auto` as the return type of functions and it will get deduced:

```
auto f() {
    return ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::filter([](int l){return l>5;});
}
// f's return type is the type of the return expression, exactly as is I had:
// auto returnValue = return-expression;
// where f's type is decltype(returnValue)
```

The only downside is that the definition of `f` has to appear in the same TU where you are using it.

Comment: I would say `auto const f() { ...` because the return value does not change. The only changing thing here is what the return value calculates lazily.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg No no no no you don't want that. You are right it doesn't change, but marking it as `const` inhibits move semantics and so the range will get copied instead of moved. I don't know how expensive that is, but a move is cheaper :)