# how do to declare a range::v3::View variable from an unknown view

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have almost the same question as a previous post:
  ["How do you declare a ranges-v3 view return value?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600644/how-do-you-declare-a-ranges-v3-view-return-value)

But that answer simply said to avoid declaring a return type and use `auto` instead, which doesn't solve my problem, and I can't find this question anywhere.

I need to create a struct that holds some type of view returned by one of several functions determined at run-time. Here a code fragment based on the cited post. The other functions are similar, just with different view types;

```
auto my_view(...)
{ // ...
    return ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::filter([](int l){return l>5;});
}
```

My first instinct is to make template struct based on the type returned, and I think that would do the trick, but I how do I do that without a typename ?

How can I declare such a class variable?

Also, because my situation is actually more complicated than above, a template would not be ideal. I would prefer if there is a way to hold any view a non-template struct?

Comment: [`ranges::any_view`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/any_view.cpp)?

Comment: `decltype` might help, but lambda has to been removed...

Comment: ranges::any_view<Container::value_type> as a class member seems to work. I'll test that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ranges::any_view was the answer that best solved my problem

I'm able to create a structure with a member any_view<value_type> and use it like you would expect from a typical ranges::view, without having to know the exact type